# Error luego de actualizar a Genexus 15 de U3 a U4

Tags: genexus

Al actualizar la aplicación en producción haciendo uso de la herramienta para Deploy, veo que no se está conectando al SQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde las aplicaciones de aministración me sigo conectando sin problemas al SQL por lo que descarté que haya pasado algo con el mismo.

Probé obteniendo el ConnectionString que está utilizando Genexus y veo que no lo está desencriptando.

```
Data Source=HM92/d8lXXXXXXXxju9Nj==;;User ID=Elj20MqY44RPXXXXXXX==;Password=veH8whpWmu+f6lj2s42IWxNHoXXXXXXXXX=;Integrated Security=no;;database=TributXXX
```

¿A alguien le pasó? ¿alguna solución o work arround?

*Para obtener el Connection String utilizo:* `((GxDataStore)dsDefault).ConnectionString;`

Comment: Para obtener el Connection String utilizo: ((GxDataStore)dsDefault).ConnectionString;

Comment: Momentáneamente pude hacerlo funcionar, dejando en texto claro las credenciales en el web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el paso de Deploy se crea una nueva clave de encriptacion con la que se re-encriptan los datos sensibles de la conexión, y esa nueva clave queda en KeyResolver.dll que va en el directorio bin. Ambos archivos deben estar (actualizados) en el sitio de prueba. Si no desencripta bien esos datos puede ser porque no está KeyResolver.dll o está pero el web.config no tiene los datos encriptados con la nueva clave (es decir es el web.config de desarrollo).

Comment: ok, ahora que genera el KeyResolver en el deploy, también se ajusta el web.config para que sea coherente, quedo solucionado, gracias